# What I have to do to solve "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"?

Tags: java, facebook, exception, httpclient

I am trying to process the following URL via the HttpGet() method:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Cafe++Bakery&type=event&access_token=&type=event&access_token=239090718395|lqqOnRWlcJOb3QGp3G4HW2aqhlc.

And I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Invalid uri 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Cafe++Bakery&type=event&access_token=&type=event&access_token=239090718395|lqqOnRWlcJOb3QGp3G4HW2aqhlc.': Invalid query
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:222)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.<init>(GetMethod.java:89)
```

Now when I cut & paste that URL into the browswer it works just fine.  I am
guess it is some sort of URL Encoding that needs to occur, but I am not sure what I have to change to call url from Http Client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try url-encoding the `|`. Its code is `%7C`.

Comment: The title of your question is really bad ^^, as if IllegalArgumentExceptions only happen within HttpGet xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [URLEncoder.encode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to encode the URL

Comment: URLEncoder.encode()  method was deprecated in API level 1.
Use encode(String, String) instead.
Equivalent to encode(s, "UTF-8").

Answer (score 3):

The URL you are trying to connect to is not a valid URL according to [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).  The character `'|'` cannot appear unencoded in a URL; see section 2.2.

Using `URLEncoder.encode()` is NOT the answer.  The problem is that `URLEncoder.encode()` is not designed for this task.  Rather it is designed for encoding raw character data to the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" MIME format.  This will:

- %-encode a characters such as `'/'`, `':'`, `'?'` and so on, in addition to the troublesome `'|'`,
- %-encode any `'%'` characters ... resulting in double %-encoding , and
- replace any space characters with `'+'` characters, resulting in URL mangling.

(Refer to the javadoc for [`UrlEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for a precise spec of what characters are encoded, and how.)

All of these incorrect / over-zealous can be harmful, depending on how the web server handles the URLs.  In the name of security, a lot of webservers cope with URLs where syntactically significant characters have been encoded unnecessarily, and will repeatedly decode until no valid-looking %-encoding sequences remain.  So in a lot of cases, you can get away with using `URLEncoder`.

But no webserver should attempt to turn `'+'` characters into space characters.  And some of the defensive tricks can be problematical; e.g. if you really need to send a `'%'` data character in the URL.

So what is the real solution?  Unfortunately it is difficult.  The correct thing to do is to parse the URL into its constituent parts using a parser that is tolerant of URL syntax errors, and the put it back together relying on the URL (or URI) class to encode the components correctly *as required by the URL / URI specifications*.

Alternatively, reject the URL.  After all, it **is** invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, url looks normal as normal it can be , no visible strange characters or anything.

Solved prob with sending URL thru this:

```
return new String(maybeIncorrectUrl.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

`maybeIncorrectUrl` beeing problematic url.